# Add a new reason for a comment to be flagged

Tags: feature-request, flags, comment-flags

I'm very familiar with posts and comments that have "Thank you" or "Thanks" in them. With comments, I use the moderator attention flag and then write This is a "Thank you" comment.

However I am getting quite bored with having to write that every day I find a "Thank you" comment.

It would be much easier if there was a "thank you" comment reason for flagging a comment with a description that says Comments that say "thank you" or "thanks" are generally not needed due to upvotes and accepting answers because they all mean "thank you"..

That way, I don't have to always click on "Something else" and then write This is a "Thank you" comment. After a few times, I get bored and want to flag directly.

I am suggesting a new reason for a comment flag which is "thank you" comment`reason.

Lots of "Thank you" flags are automatically taken care of but this is to remove the "thank you" comments faster.

Comment: How about *It's no longer needed*?

Comment: @JeanneDark `no longer needed` is not very specific.

Comment: But it is completely appropriate. Use that reason for that kind of comment.

Comment: Could you please clarify couple points - why do you think these comments need to be "remove ... faster" and whether you expect any additional actions (i.e. warning to author) that should be taken as result of this new type of flag? (So far I don't see any reasons for new flagging level as rene's and my answer show)

Comment: @zixuan: yet that's **exactly the right flag** for those comments.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A *no longer needed* is the correct flag for the type of comments you describe.

Moderators don't need extra context to understand you're flagging those type of comments because of their *thank you* nature. They are capable of working that out on their own. And in 9 out 10 cases the comment will be instantly deleted, without needing a mod at all. By using a custom flag you're actually adding to the time it takes to remove that type of comments.

You use a custom flag only if you want the mod to take notice of more context that is not immediately obvious from the comment when handled in pure isolation. Comments that say *Thank you* in various forms don't fall in this category.

In case you have doubts about the succes rate of these type of flags: I have raised over 6000 comment flags with 15 declined and the majority of those would be no longer needed flags on *thanks*.

Don't overthink comment flagging. Our moderators don't need to have spelled out each category of comments in their queue for them to make the right decision. They delete the comment anyway.